# Get dom element by ID in WebView UWP

Tags: javascript, c#, xaml, webview, uwp

I intend to get the content of a dom element from a website, I cant use

```
var html = await client.GetAsync("http://example.com/test.html");
```

as the specific dom element is populated after the JS is executed
I can use a webview to host the content but that won't solve the problem
I can't use [HtmlDocument.GetElementById Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementbyid(v=vs.110).aspx) either as it is under System.Windows.Forms namespace which isn't supported in Universal Windows Platform!
Another option would be InvokeAsync

```
await webView5.InvokeScriptAsync("doSomething", null);
```

as seen in scenario 5 of [XAML WebView control sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-WebView-control-sample-58ad63f7/sourcecode?fileId=57963&pathId=615171658)
but that just fires events and won't help in getting the dom element (or even the source code once the JS execution done).
//The app is a C# UWP, not Winjs

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) library to query DOM you downloaded. See [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40149954/2279177) or search for more, there are plenty.

Alternatively, you can run javascript which does what you need and returns a string containing your ID. As you see, `InvokeScriptAsync` returns `String` which can contain anything your javascript returned. F.e., [this is how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39844236/2279177) to get DOM with javascript:

```
var result = await this.webView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] { "document.documentElement.outerHTML;" });
```